# How to prevent docker load image from cache?

Tags: linux, docker, fedora

I loaded image with the following command:

```
$ docker load -i image.tar
```

I had something like this in image list:

`$ docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
sandbox-hdp         latest              c3cef4760133        8 weeks ago         12.2GB`

Then I decided to remove it:

```
$ docker rmi c3c
```

But when I loaded image again and run `$ docker images` I got the same output. It is not newly created image.

I tried `$ docker system prune` to clear a cache, but it didn't help. How can I load an image as a new one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the image from the same archive ([`docker load -i image.tar`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/), or more recently [`docker image load -i`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_load/#description)), you *should* get the same image (meaning with the same image ID)

Clearing the cache would not change that.

Comment: Is there anything that would change that?

Comment: @ipatina my point is: it is not a bug, it is a feature: being able to get the exact same image from an archive ensure you are able to start containers from a known reproducible state. The real question is: what is your actual issue here? (as in https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/6309) Why getting the same image is problematic (especially when you are getting it from the exact same unchanged file)